# Spring MVC controller inheritance overriding handler method

Tags: spring, inheritance, spring-mvc, controller

I have one controller that is configured with session authentication for /session_auth_uri as below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/session_auth_uri")
public class BaseController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/do", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =    "application/json", produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public Result do(@RequestBody Query query) throws SomeException {
    return new Result();
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/exec", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =    "application/json", produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public Result exec(@RequestBody Query query) throws SomeException {
    return new Result();
  }
}
```

I want to extend BaseController to reuse 1 handler method => do(...) (basic authentication is used for /basic_auth_uri):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/basic_auth_uri")
public class SubclassController extends BaseController {
}
```

The problem is that I want to be returned HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED for exec(...) handler method when accessing /basic_auth_uri/exec.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of any other way than overriding it in SubclassController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/basic_auth_uri")
public class SubclassController extends BaseController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/exec", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =    "application/json", produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
  public Result exec(@RequestBody Query query) throws SomeException {
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Indeed this works in case I provide a valid JSON serialized Query in the request. If I provide nothing in the request I get 500 - Internal server error because of MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter; if I provide an invalid input in the request I get a JSONParseException; suppose we have an @ExceptionHandler method for RuntimeException and that returns 200 OK and the exception message in the response. I was thinking of something like: no matter what the request input is => always return the 501 - NOT IMPLEMENTED response status. Is there a way to have that?

Comment: I get the 501 - Not Implemented HTTP status code only if I remove the @RequestBody annotation.